# Where is documentation about filtering operators supported by OneDrive for Business?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Currently [documentation about $filter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter) says:

> `$filter` has a very rich and expressive syntax with many built-in operators. Logical operators include equals (`eq`), not equals (`ne`), greater than (`gt`), greater than or equals (`gte`), and (`and`), or (`or`), not (`not`) etc. Arithmetic operators include add (`add`), subtract (`sub`), etc. String operators include contains (`contains`), starts with (`startswith`), etc. Lambda operators include any (`any`) and all (`all`). For additional details on $filter syntax, [see the OData protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358).

And *OneDrive personal* account works fine, it's similar that OneDrive personal support all type of filtration.

But *OneDrive for Business* returns error even on `startswith` and `endwith` operators. Looks like it doesn't support big part of filtration methods. But,
WHERE IS DOCUMENTATION about SUPPORTED filter operators? Why I have to manually check all required for me parameter? And why ["Known issues with Microsoft Graph"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues) doesn't not contain any information about filtering issues in OneDrive for Business?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to why this wasn't included in the Graph documentation (it clearly should be). This is however mentioned in the [OneDrive API documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/filtering.htm):

> **Note:** In OneDrive for Business, SharePoint Online and SharePoint
>   Server 2016, filtering support only `name` and `url` properties.

Comment: Thanks, but even for `name` it doesn't support operator `startswith`... So, it isn't full information. But it's better than nothing.